# belongsTo relationship not working as it should?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have this relation in my model:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'title', 'description', 'main_image', 'price', 'category_id', 'in_stock', 'ammount', 'status', 'quatable', 'images'
    ];

    public function enabled_category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Categories', 'category_id')->where('enabled', 'yes');
    }

}
```

And I'm trying to get product that belong to categories that are enabled, where enabled == yes

So i'm getting them like this:

```
$products = Product::with('enabled_category')->get();
```

But i still get products with disabled categories, where categories.enabled == 'no'

In my phpdebugbar I only see this 2 queries being called:

```
select * from `products`


select * from `categories` where `enabled` = 'yes' and `categories`.`id` in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49')
```

And I still get all the products, even those with disabled category.

Why is this happeining and how I can get products that belong only to enabled categories?

Comment: I think you should go the other way around, get enabled categories with their products like: `Category::where("enabled", "yes")->with("products")->get(["products.*"]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is doing exactly what you asked for...

```
$products = Product::with('enabled_category')->get();
```

You are basically telling Eloquent, fetch all products and eager load for those products the enabled_category relationship. So it will load all the products thus

```
select * from `products`
```

And then eager load the relationship for those products (the in list is the product id for which to load the relation, note your where clause is included in there, so no eager loading of enabled=no, as it should... nice optimization there, only 2 queries...)

```
select * from `categories` where `enabled` = 'yes' and `categories`.`id` in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49')
```

@NetGuy suggested an easy reversal of the query... which is really what you are looking for.

```
Category::where("enabled", "yes")->with("products")->get();
```

You simply need to define the product relationship in your Category...

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Based in the documentation in [Eloquent: Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations), you are trying to query results directly in the dynamic properties. Try doing this:

In your Model

```
public function enabled_category() {return $this->belongsTo('App\Categories', 'category_id'); }
```

And then in your controller

Category::where("enabled", "yes")->with("products")->get();

It should work!